# compile and build jar of asmack

Tags: java, build, jar, asmack

i want to do some necessary changes by applying patch in `asmack` library but i don't know how can i `compile and build` the source and generate jar file from that.

can anyone suggest me the steps to do so ?

i tried to download the source in eclipse but to build the source its asking for `main` the entry point method but i don't know where is it. i guess i doing something wrong.

here is the link [asmack](http://code.google.com/p/asmack/downloads/list) library source

Comment: down voters better you give reason for down votes !!!!!

Comment: Same problem here. I need a ant build (xml) file for building the asmack library. The Smack version does contain a working ant build file, but ASmack does not :(

Answer (score 1):

here is what I did:

1. cloned the Flow's asmack git repo:

   `git clone https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack.git`
2. modified the build.bash  by

   a.) Changing the **git://** to  **https://**  (corporate network did not allow git:// )

   b.) Change the git://kenai.org repo to https://github.com/pageone/jbosh.git  repo on Line 89:

   `execute gitfetch "https://github.com/pageone/jbosh.git" "master" "jbosh"`

   c.) Added another variable:

   `SMACK_REPO_HTTP=https://github.com/Flowdalic/smack.git`

   and modified Line 77 from

   `execute gitfetch "$SMACK_REPO" "$SMACK_BRANCH" "smack"

   to`

   execute gitfetch **"$SMACK_REPO_HTTP"** "$SMACK_BRANCH" "smack"

3.)   Deleted some patches related to jbosh as pageone's repo already had them patched.

```
<code>
patch/42-fix-regexp-compile.patch
patch/35-pin-jbosh-boddy-parser.patch
patch/34-pin-jbosh-http-sender.patch
patch/33-jbosh-android.patch
patch/32-remove-jbosh-xlightweb.sh
</code>
```

4.) now run

`bash build.bash`

Hope it works for you.